# Timestamp format adding 17 hours

Tags: java, time, timestamp

**The problem** is the `SimpleDateFormat` seems to be adding 17 hours to the actual timestamp.

This should be something really simple. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a method that will convert a long of nanoseconds to a formatted timestamp. It's adding 17 hours. Here's my [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

```
package playground;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
*
* @author kentcdodds
*/
public class NanosecondsToString {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long nanoseconds = 234236402;
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(nanoseconds, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String formatted = format.format(ts);
    System.out.println(formatted);
  }
}
```

The output: `17:00:00:234`

I'm in Mountain Standard Time

Comment: Is it doing some timezone calucation for you?  Where are you in relation to GMT?

Comment: I'm in Mountain Standard Time

Comment: While your SSCCE is much better than most, is it really a SSCCE without import statements?  Not everyone fires up an IDE for short problems.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Good point. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the timezone to `UTC`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              long nanoseconds = 234236402;
              Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(nanoseconds, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
              SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
              format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
              String formatted = format.format(ts);
              System.out.println(formatted);
    }
```

`SimpleDateFormat` will convert the timestamp to a time in your current time zone by default. So it is necessary to tell it to assume it as UTC. Otherwise, you can use [jodatime's interval class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html).

Answer (score 1):

What timezone is your machine in?  Is it possibly doing a timezone conversion?

If so using the Java TimeZone class may be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

In formatting with SimpleDateFormat, you are implicitly converting a duration into a date.  To format that date semi-safely do the formatting in the GMT timezone, without DST.  This will still have problems when encountering +24 hour durations.

A better solution is to code up a Duration class, and a SimpleDurationFormat class.  It is a pain, but you only need to do this once.  Alternatives exist too, like sucking in JodaTime,  which has explicit support for Durations (although I never had to format one).